# Reactjs Dockerisation Faild

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

What is this error? I cant run reactjs project in docker. I tried to run reactjs project in docker by docker-container using docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile

```
app                | npm ERR! syscall open
app                | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
app                | npm ERR! errno -2
app                | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open    '/app/package.json'
app                | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a  file.
app                | npm ERR! enoent 
app                | 
app                | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app                | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-25T09_02_12_947Z-debug-0.log
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:

 pdp-front:

    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: pdp-front/Dockerfile
    command: npm run start
    container_name: app
    ports:
        - "9999:9999"        
    volumes: 
        - ./:/pdp-front
        - /pdp-front/node_modules
```

Dockerfile

```
 FROM node:alpine as builder

 WORKDIR /app

 COPY pdp-front/package.json ./app

 RUN npm install

 COPY . ./

 ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

 CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Change `COPY pdp-front/package.json ./app` to `COPY pdp-front/package.json .`

Comment: Not worked.. same error showing after changing..

Comment: when you build the Dockerfile what do you get during the COPY step? post some logs maybe

Answer (score 0):

You're dropping content into several different paths inside the container.  I expect, if you `docker-compose run pdp-front sh` to get an interactive shell and look around, you'll see a file `/app/app` that's actually the `package.json` file, and then the rest of your application is inside a subdirectory `/app/pdp-front/...`.

The easiest approach here is to set up the `pdp-front/Dockerfile` so that it installs an image based only on its own directory.  So for any `COPY` instructions, the left-hand side will be relative to the `pdp-front` directory, and the right-hand side will be relative to the specified `WORKDIR`.  The Dockerfile can look like:

```sh
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./  # <-- no subdirectories on either side of this
RUN npm install

COPY . ./
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then in the `docker-compose.yml` file, you can specify the `pdp-front` directory as the build context directory and then use the default `dockerfile: Dockerfile` setting relative to that directory.  Eliminating some other unnecessary options, this can reduce to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
 pdp-front:
    build: ./pdp-front
    ports:
        - "9999:9999"
```

You need the `build: { context: ., dockerfile: pdp-front/Dockerfile }` in the case where the application needs content from one of its sibling directories.  In this case you'll need to work out the right directory layout; perhaps

```sh
WORKDIR /app/pdp-front  # default to the application-specific subdirectory
COPY pdp-front/package.json ./  # and install its specific dependencies
RUN npm ci

COPY . /app/            # copy the entire multi-project tree into /app
# RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]    # with the pdp-front subdirectory as WORKDIR
```